# Can't subtract one double from another?

Tags: java, string, double

Im quite new to Java and programming in general, but Ive read up on it quite a bit. Im currently making my first real OOP- a calculator that can perform certain equations. 
However, while trying to program something that would calculate the variance of a distribution -Heres the code:

```
void variance() {
  System.out.println("The variance of a distribution with x values of " + a + b + "and mean" 
                + mean + "is " + a*a+b*b/2 - mean*mean); 
}
```

I get the error

> Bad operand types for binary operator '-'
>                      First type = string
>                      Second type = double".

I had previously stated that a, b and mean were doubles and had also stated how mean is calculated. I also tried changing `a*a+b*b/2` from a string to a double, but then realized that if i put any integers or doubles into where `a*a+b*b/2` (e.g. 2) but i get the same error.
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: where did you declare **mean**

Comment: put brackets around the expression `(a*a+b*b/2 - mean*mean)`

Comment: by the way, these are brackets: `[]` while these are parentheses: `()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the `+` is overloaded in Java for string concatenation.  You need to put parentheses around your math expression.

```
System.out.println("The variance of a distribution with x values of " + a + b + "and mean" 
 + mean + "is " + (a*a+b*b/2 - mean*mean));
```

Comment: +1 May I also suggest the OP actually wants `((a*a+b*b)/2.0 - mean*mean)`

Comment: They might need that; I didn't want to confuse the issue with whether or not the formula was mathematically correct.

Comment: Perfect use for a comment... ook ook eek eek.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you need to do this:

```
            + mean + "is " + (a*a+b*b/2 - mean*mean));
```

The longer answer is that Java evaluates your expression from left to right. So step by step, it happens something like this:

1. mean + "is " + a*a+b*b/2 - mean*mean
2. *string* + "is " + a*a+b*b/2 - mean*mean
3. *string* + a*a+b*b/2 - mean*mean
4. *string* - mean*mean

The compiler stops here because although you can *concatenate* a string and a number using `+` (in step 3), it doesn't make sense to *subtract* a number from a string. By using parentheses around the whole arithmetic expression, that will cause the arithmetic to be evaluated first, before the result is concatenated with the rest of your output string.

Comment: +1, but a nit: Java evaluates *operands* from left to right, for any given operator. It evaluates expressions according to operator precedence.

Answer (score 2):

Surround all mathematical expressions between parenthesis, and (depending on the actual type of `a`, `b`, `mean`), it's better to divide by `2.0`, to make sure that a floating-point division is performed.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing the `String` `+` operator with the `Double` operator.

Try this:

```
System.out.println( "The variance of a distribution with x values of " 
    + ( a + b ) + " and mean " 
    + mean + " is " 
    + ( ( a * a + b * b / 2 ) - ( mean * mean )) );
```